# Exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f'(c)\leq 2f(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow (-\infty ,0]$ be a differentiable function, with $f(0)=0$. Prove that exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that $f'(c)\leq 2f(c)$

Comment: Well, if $f'(0)>0$, then...

Comment: $f'(0)$ can't be greater than $0$, because the function is $\le0$

Comment: Are you sure you wrote what you meant to ask? The problem seems more interesting if we only know that $f $ is differentiable on $(0,1) $, but perhaps not at $0$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g:[0,1]\to(-\infty,0]$ defined as $g(x)=e^{-2x}f(x)$. Then $g(0)=0$. If $g'(0)>0$, then $\exists \delta\in(0,1)$ such that $g(0)>0$ which is not possible. Hence $g'(0)\le0$. Now $g'(x)=e^{-2x}(f'(x)-2f(x))$, so $g'(0)\le0$ implies $f'(0)\le2f(0)$.

Comment: This is too complicated. You can conclude $f'(0)\le0$ directly from the definition of derivative

Comment: Yeah that would have done perfectly, I just wanted to show where the expression $f'(x)-2f(x)$ might have come from. This was actually easy. I wanted to show how to handle the problem if one needed to find $c$ from the open interval $(0,1)$